# How to loop form/new entity in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having an issue with looping a form in Symfony using while loop. When the user enters one student period and it matches a registration reiterate the form to let them enter a 2nd student period and then a 3rd. I'm not doing it correctly or could I reiterate entity=new Student(); to let them enter two entities .

```
public function createAction(Request $request){
    $entity = new Student();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $student = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Payrollperiod')
                    ->findOneBy([
                        'begindate'=>$form->get('beginDate')->getData(),
                        'lastdate'=>$form->get('lastDate')->getData()
                    ]);

        $registration = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Payrollweek')
                    ->findBystartdateAndenddate(
                        $form->get('beginDate')->getData(),
                        $form->get('lastDate')->getData()
                    );

        $counter = count($registration);

        while($counter<=2) {
            if ($student){
                    $this->addFlash('error', 'Duplicate error: Student Period already existed.' );
                    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student'));
            }
            elseif ($registration){  
                foreach ($registration as $reg) {
                    $reg->setStudentid($entity); 
                }
                $em->persist($entity);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('payrollperiod'));
            }
            else{
                $this->addFlash('error', ' does not match .');
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('student')); 
            }
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );   

    }
}
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems in your design and I don't think it's going to do what you expect.

Comment: Agreed.  This is not how web requests work

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#allow-extra-fields on adding fields.  Your UI/Front-end should created more fields when the user needs to add a second or more periods. I should generate proper Symfony form elements and then when you post, you can handle it like a standard form post, iterating over the Request since the periods will be submitted as an array.

I did something like this in the past I adding a new form row was an AJAX call to a template that described the form input fields so I wasn't having to craft form HTML in Javascript/jQuery.  `.append()` the template results to the form-- post and process the request.